# The antonym of political-savvy

Tags: antonyms

People sometimes use "political-savvy" to describe someone who is aware of what to do or what not to do in an organization or company. I wonder which word would be the opposite of that? i.e. someone who doesn't have that set of political (business, communication) skills.

Comment: Lacking in people skills.

Comment: When they're sure they won't be overheard, I imagine the "savvy" people refer to the others as *resources* (or maybe *sheep*). But I expect OP is looking for a more "positive" expression.

Comment: I like "Palinesq"

Comment: This isn't a practical answer to your question (anymore?), but it might amuse you: The term "idiot", to the ancient Greeks (who originally used it), meant someone who did not participate in politics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could go with "political-naïveté", where naive is an antonym for savvy.

> [**na·ive**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/naive)  [nah-eev] *adjective*
>
> **1.** having or showing unaffected simplicity of nature or absence of artificiality; unsophisticated; ingenuous.
>
> **2.** having or showing a lack of experience, judgment, or information; credulous: *She's so naive she believes everything she reads. He has a very naive attitude toward politics.*

<sub>Source: NAIVE. (n.d.). *Dictionary.com Unabridged*. Retrieved April 18, 2014, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/NAIVE</sub>

As a bonus, savvy and naive both have roots in the romance languages, being primarily from Spanish/French and French respectively.

Comment: Plus, "naïve" has a great noun form: *naïf* (a naïve person).  For "savvy", I guess you would have to go to *maven* for the noun.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean politically savvy? The opposite? Pehaps politically unaware, a newcomer to politics, a political innocent.

Answer (score 1):

How about "political ignoramus," "political retard," and "[political passivist](http://www.jonathan-cook.net/blog/2014-01-21/our-political-passivity-was-engineered/)?"

> ["Are you a political ignoramus?"](http://www.maderatribune.com/columns/are-you-political-ignoramus)
>
> [Confession of a political retard](http://lauritasplace.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/confessions-of-a-political-retard-34-2/).

Also, on fairly different levels, consider "[political don't-give-a-damnist](http://beaglescout.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/the-care-and-nurture-of-future-ex-democrats/)" and "[political apathist](http://www.nickjenkins.net/prose/rant.html)."

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term "*politically inept*", as an adjective. There's even a [Simpsons episode](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Politically_Inept,_with_Homer_Simpson) that uses this phrase in its title.

Unfortunately, the noun form, "*political-ineptness*" or "*political-ineptitude*", is not very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who totally lacks political savvy, but tries to exercise it anyway:  **loose cannon**?

Answer (score 1):

Someone who is politically savvy is saying the right things to the right people.  Often bending the truth or keeping their lips closed if they have any issues.

So two words that would describe the opposite behavior...

- **honest**
- **blunt**

Answer (score 0):

Less formally, 'unsavvy' is the antonym of 'savvy'. (not that 'savvy' is particularly formal!)

Answer (score 0):

**Do-nothing**: always used before a noun
1 : not willing to work, help, etc.
: lazy[enter link description here](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/38421/do-nothing)

```
a do-nothing husband
```

2 : failing to achieve or do anything important

```
a do-nothing policy/government/politician
```

Answer (score 0):

Political cretinism

I've been hearing people say that about themselves mockingly. It's not that they actually consider themselves cretins in that aspect, but objectively assess their own level of knowledge as very low.

Answer (score -1):

Politically ignoramus will be the opposite

Comment: An explanation with a citation is welcome.  Please take a moment to see the [help].